# Remove dots and commas from column values

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008

I migrated some data from MySql; the migration of data was successful but some values contain data with dots and commas.

What is the best way to remove these characters from my data?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

in sql server you can use REPLACE for remove data and STUFF to add data

as follows

```
replace('Your String','charater you want to replace','with what')


stuff('Your String',position,count,'data')
```

Answer (score 15):

In SQL SERVER you could use [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('abc,123.456', ',', ''), '.', '')
```