# How to remove all commas in query result - (i have 300+ columns in my table)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with numerous column, I want to remove all commas in the data using single select query

I tried `replace`, but it is tedious if I apply replace in all columns

Sample:

```
REPLACE([Pay-to City], ',', ' ')[Pay-to City]
```

[Sample image Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WMaV.png)

Comment: If the *reason* for doing this is so that CSV output isn't messed up, you might consider quoting the cells in the CSV. If you write output like "John","Smith, Jr" most CSV readers including Excel will treat that as two columns without surrounding quotes.

Comment: you mean i have to qoute the cells everytime in the .csv? by the way, the extraction is automated by shell script and output as .csv, thats why it should be done automatically.

Comment: If you have valid commas in your cells, yes, that's the way to handle them. Depending on your SQL dialect one method might be SELECT '"' + col1 + "'" FROM Table. I usually handle the quoting in a programming language personally.

Comment: Note that if you have valid *quotes* in your data, you escape those by double-quoting them. Example: "John ""Smitty"" Smith, Jr" is the escaped form of John "Smitty" Smith, Jr

Comment: its tedious to edit numerous extract everyday,

Comment: you can try this following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956330/remove-dots-and-commas-from-column-values

Comment: @Cel, could you provide example data and RDBMS you are using?

Comment: it's going to be one time action or saved as some kind of view?

Comment: @Whencesoever - its for one time action, i'll be needing the query for daily automated extraction.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - im using MSSQL 2013, tag added..

Comment: @daud - i already tried to use Replace, and its very tedious cause i have 300+ columns

Comment: im thinking if there's some sql query that can remove all comma's on the query result.

Comment: csv output is messed up due to the commas in my data.

Comment: @Cel but in csv You have something like Text qualifier. You can set it to " for example and when import such csv You also set that Your csv have it as text qualifier and commas are not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is messed up in the CSV i.e. the database, then it's likely you need to sanitize your inputs. Otherwise how are you to distinguish which commas are desired column separators and which are the ones to be removed? With 300+ columns you should be able to write a Perl or shell script to quickly parse the data *if* you can programmatically determine which commas are delete... able.